# Using label expression to label highway with last group of numbers in field

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, labeling, vbscript, expression

I'm using Tiger road files and I want to label the highways with their shield number. Tiger has an inconsistent naming convention for road features; I am specifically concerned with the highways. I have defined 3 seperate label classes: interstate, US, and state route. For each I applied an SQL query of their corresponding route types.

The part I am struggling with is creating a label expression for each that would include only the last SET of numbers. I say "set" because there are varying numbers of characters annotating the highway number.

Example:
US Hwy 24,
US Hwy 6,
State Hwy 78 N

Is there a way to include only the highway number for the label?

Comment: Using your example what would you want the label to show?

Answer (score 1):

Update: I found the solution in the following link under "Extract a number."
Be sure to select "advanced" in the label expression dialog.

http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/20154

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option using python within the label expression (less code):

```
def FindLabel ( [MYFIELDNAME] ):
  try:
    return ''.join(i for i in [MYFIELDNAME]  if i.isdigit()) 
  except ValueError:
    pass
```

Make sure you change the Parser to Python and check the Advanced checkbox.